# I am the closest friend to your son. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am the closest friend to your son.
>
> If your son's mass is 100kg, then my mass is 110kg.
>
> I am slightly brighter than your son.

Who am I?

*There is a word mispelled in the riddle, if you find it, then the riddle becomes easier.*

Comment: Given the field of the accepted answer, no answer can fit the riddle as it is written.  The closest friend does not match the mass and brightness comparisons.

Comment: You're his brother.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @WBT may I know what is wrong??

Comment: @AmruthA I'm not saying there's anything wrong with the question. I'm giving a somewhat humorous answer, that is too short and different from the accepted answer to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> Alpha Centauri

Explanation:

> 'Son' is misspelt - it should be 'Sun'
>  It is the closest star to the Sun. The mass/brightness ratios should work out too.

Comment: According to this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri) the answer must be Alpha Centauri A specifically as it has a 1.10 Solar Mass, Alpha Centauri B is only .907

Comment: @DasBeasto Neither A nor B are the closest.

Comment: @Muqo Well if neither are closer than they both fit the first line of the riddle (or don't fit?), but only A fits the second line of the riddle  as B is not 1.1 times the mass of our Son(sun), making it the more accurate answer. I'm just being pedantic though clearly this is correct.

Comment: @DasBeasto Proxima Centauri is currently the closest.  Amruth A simply needs to modify the first line of the riddle.

Comment: @Muqo just asking Is Alpha Centauri not the nearest  star to our solar system ?

Comment: @Muqo check https://www.google.co.in/search?q=which+is+the+closet+star+to+sun&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=eSakV_P1DsvbvAT8krIw

Comment: @Amruth Correct, Alpha Centauri is not the nearest star to our solar system, as you can see by reading most if not all of the pages resulting from the search you posted a link to.